# What's the simples way to handle interactions between multiple js files while avoiding to spill global variables?

Tags: javascript

A while ago I started [this simple toy project](http://ericviala.github.io/Skwares/) for my own self. It grew.

I now have 5 separate .js files that need to interact, ie I want to be able to initialize an object in `a.js` then use it in `b.js`

In order to avoid spilling variables to the global environment (in this case the `Window` object) I pack all the shared variables into one global object with an improbable name (namely Skwares). So far it's good enough for my modest development environment, but for the sake of learning, and with the ulterior hypothetical intent of releasing it, I'd like to make it better.

Of course, I could gather everything in a single file and wrap it in a IIFE, but that does not seem very flexible for a work in progress, does it ?

I understand there exist tools like Require.js or Bowser.js but they seem to be a bit of an overkill here, and I'm not quite ready yet to invest the time and effort to learn how to use them. I also confusely feel that while learning, I'd better stick as much as possible to vanilla.js

What would Crockford do ?

Comment: If you're definitely sold on not using a module bundler/loader of any kind, your best bet is probably to implement some variant of the [Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/).

Comment: Are the dependencies two-way or one-way? Do both files need variables from each other?

Comment: @JoeClay : bingo, that's precisely what I was confusely thinking of, explained beautifuly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ÉricViala: Glad I could help! If you do decide to move up to a module bundler at some point, I'd recommend Webpack or Browserify over Require.js - I think they're way more flexible/less verbose to use. That said, there's nothing wrong with just sticking to vanilla JavaScript - people survived with the module pattern for years before those tools existed, and I think there's a lot to be said for learning the language before adding a pile of extra tooling on top of it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about [namespace pattern](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) in order to organize your code.

You can use some task manager (grunt, gulp or so) to automatize the building of a distributable package (typically /dist), concat all files in order and minify it, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. When (and if) I'll understand everything that's in there, I'll be really confortable. As for Grunt, Gulp & Co, I understand that's it is unavoidable that I eventually get there, not just right now though.